# Error on installing downloaded Chrome .deb

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, dependencies

I have downloaded Chrome on 14.04 as .deb package. Whenever I try to install it, it gives error  "Dependency is not satisfiable".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have all checked under Software & Updates --> Update tab, then do

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

An easier way to install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

> ```
> wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
> ```

Or use synaptics

<sup>Source:[TecAdmin](http://tecadmin.net/)</sup>